# COUNT after join and group by in PIG

Tags: hdfs, apache-pig

I'm new in pig and trying understand why I can not count after join and group by:

```
A = LOAD 'mary' as (line);
B = LOAD 'mary' as (line);

wordsA = foreach A generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line)) as wordA;
grpdA = group wordsA by wordA;
cntdA = foreach grpdA generate group, COUNT(wordsA);

wordsB = foreach B generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line)) as wordB;
grpdB = group wordsB by wordB;
cntdB = foreach grpdB generate group, COUNT(wordsB), 'some text';

fltB = FILTER cntdB BY $1>1;

jnd = join cntdA by $1, fltB by $1;
jnd_n = foreach jnd generate $0;
grp = group jnd by $0;
out = foreach grp generate group, count(jnd_n);

dump jnd_n;
dump grp;
```

dump jnd_n:

```
(was)
(was)
(was)
(lamb)
(lamb)
(lamb)
(Mary)
(Mary)
(Mary)
```

dump grp:

```
(was,{(was,2,was,2,some text),(was,2,Mary,2,some text),(was,2,lamb,2,some text)})
(Mary,{(Mary,2,was,2,some text),(Mary,2,Mary,2,some text),(Mary,2,lamb,2,some text)})
(lamb,{(lamb,2,was,2,some text),(lamb,2,Mary,2,some text),(lamb,2,lamb,2,some text)})
```

But I'm getting error:

> Invalid scalar projection: jnd_n : A column needs to be projected from
>   a relation for it to be used as a scalar

If I try to change code:

```
out = foreach grp generate group, count(jnd_n.$0);
```

Then I'm getting another error:

> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
>   Could not resolve count using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

I know that I can do it another way, but I want to get result like this after exactly after doing two pig operations **JOIN** and **GROUP BY**:

dump out:

```
(was,3)
(lamb,3)
(Mary,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` needs to be in caps.  [COUNT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#count) is a keyword.

```
out = foreach grp generate group, COUNT(jnd_n.$0);`
```

Comment: Thx for answer, yes COUNT is sensitive, but got another error:

`ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1045: 
<file script.pig, line 24, column 34> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.COUNT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.`